# Polymorphism with Spring Hateoas

Tags: jackson, spring-hateoas

After trying several variants, I'm stuck in trying to make my Spring HATEOAS controller do polymorphism.

My first variant was to implement the resources as instances of `Resource`, with my object as `content`. The base class is defined as follows:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat"), @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog") })
@JsonRootName("Animal")
public abstract class Animal
{
  :
  :
}
```

When fetching a single instance or a page, the following exception is thrown:

```
Could not write content: Unwrapped property requires use of type information: can not serialize without disabling `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS`
```

The full repro is available here: https://github.com/Bert-R/spring-hateoas-polymorphism/tree/master/src/main/java/nu/famroos/spring/hateoas/polymorphism/repro1

My understanding is that this error is caused by an `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation on the `getContent` method of `Resource`. The `PagedResources` apparently uses a similar approach.

My second attempt was to make my classes inherit from `ResourceSupport`, to circumvent the `@JsonUnwrapped` issue. The base class now looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat2.class, name = "Cat2"), @Type(value = Dog2.class, name = "Dog2") })
@JsonRootName("Animal2")
public abstract class Animal2 extends ResourceSupport
{
  :
  :
}
```

This works partially. A single resource is now serialized correctly (note the `@type` property):

```
{
   "@type":"Dog2",
   "name":"nameofdog",
   "barkVolume":1.0,
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8082/animals2/nameofdog"
      }
   }
}
```

However, a page does not have the `@type` property:

```
{
   "_embedded":{
      "Animal2s":[
         {
            "name":"nameofdog",
            "barkVolume":1.0,
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"http://localhost:8082/animals2/nameofdog"
               }
            }
         },
         :
         :
      ]
   },
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8082/animals2"
      }
   },
   "page":{
      "size":20,
      "totalElements":3,
      "totalPages":1,
      "number":0
   }
}
```

The code of this repro is available here: https://github.com/Bert-R/spring-hateoas-polymorphism/tree/master/src/main/java/nu/famroos/spring/hateoas/polymorphism/repro2

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain a way to make polymorphism work in combination with Spring HATEOAS.

Answer (score 3):

After looking further, I found out the reason why the `@type` attribute is not included in a page of resources: type erasure. See [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336).

There is a workaround for this: Instead of `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`, use `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` and add a property to each subclass that returns the type. It's not elegant, but it allows to implement a polymorphic API. The full source code for this workaround is available here: https://github.com/Bert-R/spring-hateoas-polymorphism/tree/master/src/main/java/nu/famroos/spring/hateoas/polymorphism/workaround

P.S. For those who feel that disabling  `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS` would solve the issue in the first variant: if you disable that setting, the type information will be ignored, so the `@type` attribute won't be added during serialization.

Comment: Or simply create a typed page resource.

Comment: Could you tell more about that? What exactly did you mean?